# 8086 basic mathematic expression

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I have to do an operation like this in 8086

((x*y)-c)+1

I wrote this code:

```
.stack
.data
A dw 180
B db 4  
C dw 300 


.code
start:
    
    MOV AX, 00h
    MOV AX, A
    MUL B
    SUB AX, C
    DEC AX
    int 21h 
end start
```

This code works but I don't think does the expression I wanted...

Where am I wrong?

Comment: The code "works"? How is the interrupt `0x21` function in `AH` related to the arithmetic values you are working with?

Comment: Looking at my teacher's example he always uses 'int 21h' at the end of his code

Comment: Doesn't `MUL B` multiply `AL` * `B`, not `AX` * `B` (being an 8-bit operand)?

Comment: As I tried to imply, `int 21h` needs a **function** value in register `AH`. Here, it is the result of the arithmetic, but to terminate it should be `00h`.

Comment: Wait, I don't have to move values into my register before doing any kind of mathematic operation?

Comment: Looks like it happens to implement your expression for these input values (where `B * (uint8_t)A` is the same as `B * A`), except for doing -1 (DEC) instead of +1 (INC).  (Although it will end with `int 21h` / `AH=1` since you finish with `AX = 0x1a3`), so you're invoking DOS call number 1.  Single-step your code with a debugger and look at register values; that should make things pretty obvious.  Debugging questions always need a [mcve] that includes ctual vs. expected output values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This code works but I don't think does the expression I wanted...

> ```
> ((x * y) - c) + 1
> ```

The calculation is almost correct. Just the `DEC AX` should become `INC AX` so it matches the expression where you **add 1** in the end:

> Looking at my teacher's example he always uses `int 21h` at the end of his code

I'm sure your teacher's code will have something like `mov ah, 00h` or `mov ax, 4C00h` directly above that line. It's meant to terminate the program and return to DOS.

---

This is the code that additionally shows the result of the calculation on the screen. The program waits for a keyboard key before it terminates giving you the opportunity to actually see the outcome.

```
start:
    mov  ax, A
    mul  B
    sub  ax, C
    inc  ax         ; -> AX == 421

    mov  bx, 10
    xor  cx, cx
Divide:
    xor  dx, dx     ; Setup for division DX:AX / BX
    div  bx         ; -> Quotient AX, Remainder DX=[0,9]
    push dx         ; (1)
    inc  cx
    test ax, ax
    jnz  Divide
Show:
    pop  dx         ; (1)
    add  dl,"0"     ; [0,9] -> ["0","9"]
    mov  ah, 02h    ; DOS.DisplayCharacter
    int  21h        ; -> AL
    dec  cx
    jnz  Show

    mov  ah, 01h    ; DOS.GetKey
    int  21h        ; -> AL

    mov  ax, 4C00h  ; DOS.Terminate
    int  21h 
end start
```

Comment: If exiting your program makes it impossible to still see the output, it's your environment that's broken, not the program.

Comment: @PeterCordes If they run the program from within an IDE, then exiting the program will have removed the program's output from the screen (because the "Editor Screen" gets redrawn). Only if the IDE offers a "User Screen" will they be able to see the program's output again, but this too will require striking some key(s).  Then why not make it a habit to always wait for a key right before exiting? For example, the QBasic IDE does this already automatically.

Comment: Exactly; something that opens a new terminal for a program should have an option to keep it open after the program exits.  Most Unix/Linux terminal emulators have an option to do that, because cluttering every exit path of every toy program with a getchar() equivalent is dumb.  I was under the impression that the major mainstream IDEs *do* have such an option.